# React Hooks: Dispatch an action on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three pages, *PageA, PageB and PageC*, that contain a form element `formField`.

State in *globalReducer.js*

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
  userInteractionBegun: false,
  pageActive: '',
  refreshData: true,
})
```

I want to dispatch an action that sets `pageActive` to corresponding page value(One of *A, B or C*) when the component(page) mounts and refreshes `formField` to blank if `userInteractionBegun === false`.

For every page component, to get `pageActive` state in `props` from  *globalReducer*, I do,

```
function PageA(props) {
  //.....
}

// globalState is defined in conigureStore, I am using immutable.js. Link provided below this code.
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pageActive: state.getIn(['globalState', 'pageActive']),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PageA);
```

Link to [immutable.js getIn()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/getIn)

*store.js*

```
import globalReducer from 'path/to/globalReducer';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    globalState: globalReducer,
    //...other reducers
  })
)
```

I want to abstract the logic to update `pageActive` every time a component(page) mounts.

I know how to abstract this logic using an HOC, but I don't know how to do it using react [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), so that every time *pageA, pageB or pageC* mounts, an action to `setPageActive` is dispatched and `formField` is set to *blank* if `userInteractionBegun` is false.

---

For instance, I would do in *pageA.js*

```
import usePageActive from 'path/to/usePageActive';

const [pageActive, setPageActive] = useReducer(props.pageActive);
usePageActive(pageActive);
```

Then in *usePageActive.js*

```
export default usePageActive(pageActive) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(pageActive);
  setState(// dispatch an action //)
}
```

Comment: Can you use an effect?  "If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined." -- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @richbai90 Umm, I am want to `usePageActive` custom effect. I am not sure of how to dispatch an action from there.

Comment: I apologize I didn't understand your question at first. I think that my updated answer will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much time to dip my toes into react hooks yet, but after reading the docs and playing with it for a minute, I think this will do what you're asking. I'm using built-in state here, but you could use redux or whatever else you like in the effect. You can see a working example of this code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7k48o3j6vx?codemirror=1&fontsize=14) The trick is using a hook creator to create the custom hook. That way the parent and children can keep a reference to the same state without the useEffect affecting the parent.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const activePageFactory = (setActivePage) => (activePage) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setActivePage(activePage)
    return () => {
      setActivePage('')
    }
  }, [activePage])
  return activePage
}

function App() {
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState('');
  const [localPage, setLocalPage] = useState('Not Selected');
  const selectedPage = () => {
    switch(localPage) {
      case 'A':
        return <PageA useActivePage={activePageFactory(setActivePage)}  />
      case 'B':
        return <PageB useActivePage={activePageFactory(setActivePage)}  />
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Active page is {activePage}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setLocalPage('A')}>
        Make A Active
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setLocalPage('B')}>
        Make B Active
      </button>
      {
        selectedPage()
      }
    </div>
  );
}

function PageA({useActivePage}) {
  useActivePage('A');
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am Page A</p>
    </div>
  )
}

function PageB({useActivePage}) {
  useActivePage('B');
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am Page B</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```